# What happened to Intellisense for enum types in Visual Studio 2010 using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Prof.

In C# I can create my own Enumerator and use it like this:

```
MyEnum value =
```

Now, Intellisense will suggest a value of MyEnum.

In VB, when I write:

```
Dim value As MyEnum =
```

I get a huge list of every types. When starting to write my enumerator value (could be a word like "sunny") it filters out some types but I would like to have it like in C#. Anyway I will use the MyEnum type and no "String nor Objecte nor IntPtr...".

Any idea?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vKXH.png)

Also I made a short video:
[Video with sample](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntc8C-Rp84c) (new)

Regards

Comment: Picky semantic quibble: **An "enumerator" is *completely* different from an "enumeration".** You're talking about an enumeration, but you're calling it an enumerator.

Comment: Did you try installing SP1 for VS2010? According to some forums, this is know issue and might have been fixed in SP1. Obviously, some people still experience the issue, but it works for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a documented issue in VS 2010, pre-SP1. See: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551699/intellisense-enum-values. It has been fixed in SP1. If you can't install SP1, the only workaround is to use the mouse or **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** + **<kbd>,</kbd>** to switch from the "All" to the "Common" tab.

Comment: **Never** had that problem VS 2010 RM. And I primarily develop in VB.NET. Interesting. Things have always looked like the screenshots I posted.

Comment: It wasn't entirely consistent. I only develop in VB.NET and have had the issue on one machine but not on two others (one physical and one VM). SP1 fixed the issue on my first box.

Comment: I take that back - I also develop in VBA :)

Comment: Hey thats a good information. I am downloading now http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5

Comment: @goldengel: Cool, let me know if it works for you. It did for me.

Comment: Ok. Download and installation has taken about 40 minutes on a fast computer with 2000K download line. Manager downloaded all. Now ALL IS WORKING CORRECT. In this case: download the link above will fix this issu.

Comment: For anyone who is interested in how it look like now, I made a short video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbVmnjc6Bw4

Answer (score 4):

Simple, all you have to do is click the **"Common"** tab at the bottom of the Intellisense drop-down.
To prove it, here's a screenshot of what I see in VS 2010, immediately after typing `=`:

[image]

But, even if you have the **"All"** tab selected, the values defined in the enum will still be automatically displayed first, and even appear grouped together. You will indeed see all possible members and types, even those that are completely unrelated, but it's still pretty easy to find the ones you want.

[image]

And no, I'm not using any third-party add-ins or extensions to achieve the demonstrated feat. As best I can tell, I also haven't reconfigured any relevant options from the default settings.

Comment: And you can use Alt + . and Alt + , to switch between the two instead of reaching for the mouse.

Comment: Hi Tom. I think I did not explain exactly. Please visit: http://www.goldengel.ch/temp/screenshot%20-%202011_04_27%2009-24-15.png

Comment: @goldengel: The video doesn't tell me a whole lot, as you say it doesn't even show what you see in the Intellisense popup. From the screenshot, it looks like you have Intellisense disabled altogether, but after watching the video and reading your caption, apparently that isn't the case. As I mentioned in my answer, you see all the types if you have the "All" tab selected. The default behavior is as shown in the screenshots above. If you're seeing something different, you've somehow disabled Intellisense support for VB.NET. Check the Options dialog under the Tools menu.

Comment: @goldengel: Or perhaps a simpler solution is simply to reset all your settings. Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset All Settings.

Comment: Hi: I've re-uploaded the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntc8C-Rp84c . As you can see there, the enum is not pre-selected. That is my problem.

Comment: @goldengel: Not sure what to tell you. I can't reproduce that problem on any installation of Visual Studio, on any computer. I've never seen it before, and I spend a *lot* of time developing in VB.NET. Try reinstalling or resetting all of your settings, as I mentioned above. Either the install got corrupted, or you've turned off Intellisense support.

Comment: Any idea after watching current video?

Comment: @goldengel: I was referring to the last video you posted. I see what it's doing, but I'm unable to reproduce that problem. Start troubleshooting by resetting all of your settings: Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset All Settings.